# React | Uncaught TypeError: this.props.methodfromparent is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Relatively new to React! I keep getting this error message. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Help appreciated.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.getDataFromRun is not a function

I basically want to get the state from Run.js to TestReport.js and some guides said that it works, when I have the state object in my parent file (TestReport.js) and pass a function to my child, but somehow I always get the error message that getDataFromRun is not a function in my child component.

**TestReport.js**

```
function Overview(Component) {
  return function OverviewComponent(props) {
      const { open, toggleOpen } = React.useContext(OpenContext);
      return <Component {...props} open={open} toggleOpen={toggleOpen} />;
    }
}

class TestReport extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tests: 0,
      failedTests: 0,
      testcaseName: [],
      failureMessage: [],
      failureType: [],
      timestamp: new Date()
    }
  }
  
  getDataFromRun(data) {
    this.setState({
      tests: data.tests,
      failedTests: data.failedTests,
      testcaseName: data.testcaseName,
      failureMessage: data.failureMessage,
      failureType: data.failureType,
      timestamp: data.timestamp
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const open = this.props.open;
    const toggleOpen = this.props.toggleOpen;
    return (
       <Run getDataFromRun={this.getDataFromRun}/> {/* Shows the runs */}
    );
  }
}

export default Overview(TestReport);
```

**Run.js**

```
export default class Run extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            tests: 0,
            failedTests: 0,
            testcaseName: [],
            failureMessage: [],
            failureType: [],
            timestamp: new Date()
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // fetch tests from xml
        this.getTests().then(result => this.setState({
            tests: result.tests,
            failedTests: result.failedTests,
            testcaseName: result.testcaseName,
            failureMessage: result.failureMessage,
            failureType: result.failureType,
            timestamp: result.timestamp
        }));
        this.props.getDataFromRun(this.state);
    }

    getTests() {
        // returns data of an xml-file 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            Run with {this.state.tests} tests and {this.state.failedTests} failed        
         );
    } 
}
```

Comment: When overrriding [the constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor), you have to call super (the constructor on the inherited class) with props.

Comment: Also, `getDataFromRun(this.state)` will happen before the `setState` call above it

Comment: And how can I make the setState before the getDataFromRun? @windowsill

Comment: Well since you don't need any state on the Run component, you could change it to `this.getTests().then(this.props.getDataFromRun)`. Then you just need to send down `tests` and `failedTests` from the parent as props.

Comment: But if you did need that setState call for some reason, you can calculate the new first, then do both async calls like `getTests().then(res => { const newState={whatever}; this.setState(newState); props.getDataFromRun(newState); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind that getDataFromRun function in the constructor before you could call that function in the rendered component.
Your constructor should look like this :

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      tests: 0,
      failedTests: 0,
      testcaseName: [],
      failureMessage: [],
      failureType: [],
      timestamp: new Date()
    }
    this.getDataFromRun = this.getDataFromRun.bind(this);
  }
```

Or, use arrow function like this :

```
  const getDataFromRun = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      tests: data.tests,
      failedTests: data.failedTests,
      testcaseName: data.testcaseName,
      failureMessage: data.failureMessage,
      failureType: data.failureType,
      timestamp: data.timestamp
    });
  }
```